# Firebase Admin Node.js SDK support new FCM API

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Received this (quoted below) update from the Firebase team a little while back and I'm looking to see if this is supported yet (or possible when) in the Node SDK.  Really looking forward to the cross-platform notifications support.  Thanks!

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) gives you an easy way to send notifications to your users, either programmatically or through the Firebase Console. However, sending cross-platform notifications with more complex functionality has been difficult, sometimes requiring you to create multiple, separate messages.
>   Today, we're announcing a new RESTful, FCM HTTP v1 API that makes it safer and easier to send messages to your cross-platform applications. The new FCM API allows you to use platform-specific fields in a single notification. For example, you might send a simple text notification to iOS, but a request with a click_action to Android, all in one API call. To read more about the new FCM API, visit our documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the feature table in the [documentation for the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), it says the node SDK has support for Cloud Messaging.  Clicking that link will take you to the specific [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/) for sending messages from your node server.

Comment: Thanks for your response Doug, but maybe my question wasn't clear.  I already use FCM with my firebase-admin node server, in fact it is all I use it for.  What I'm specifically trying to find out is if or when support for the API changes mentioned above (cross-platform notifications) will be added to the node sdk.  Currently, to get the functionality that I want, I have to break out notifications by device type so that android receives one notification token and ios receives another for the same message.  I look forward to removing my complexity in support of the cross-platform notifications.